# Is it correct to say "I realize my desire for fame"?

Tags: sentence

Does this sentence sound odd?

> I realize my desire for fame by achieving the first
> rank in the competition

Comment: You mean 'realize' as in 'make real'?

Comment: @marcellothearcane I mean achieve- fulfil

Comment: The only thing that sounds odd is maybe the tense - should it not be "I _realized_ my desire for fame &c"?